# What are the pros and cons on using React Context API with the useReducer() hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm working on a web application and I'm using the React Context without using the useReducer() hook. This is a simple example of how I'm using the Context in my app:

```
const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState("");
const [stateValue1, setStateValue1] = useState("");
const contextValue : MainContext = {
      stateValue: stateValue,
      setStateValue: setStateValue,
      stateValue1: stateValue1,
      setStateValue1: setStateValue1
}
```

So I pass to my Context Provider the contextValue and every time a child component has to change the stateValuex just calls the setStateValuex so that it triggers the re-rendering of the stateValuex inside all the child components.
What would the pros and cons be on using instead the Context with the useReducer() hook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd approach it as two issues: 1) pros/cons of `useState` vs `useReducer` 2) pros/cons of props vs context. Then stick those answers together.

`useReducer` can be useful if you have a complicated state that you want to make sure all your update logic is in one centralized location. `useState` on the other hand is good for simple state where you don't need that kind of control.

props is the standard way to pass values from one component to its child. If you're passing it a short distances, this is the simplest and best approach. context is useful if you need to pass values a long way down the component tree. If you have a lot of cases where a component receives a prop not for itself, but just so it can forward it to a child, then this may indicate context would be better than props.

```
const contextValue : MainContext = {
  stateValue: stateValue,
  setStateValue: setStateValue,
  stateValue1: stateValue1,
  setStateValue1: setStateValue1
}
```

P.S: if your context value is an object, [don't forget to memoize it](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats). If you don't, you'll be creating a brand new object every time you render, and that will force any components consuming the context to render too

```
const contextValue: MainContext = useMemo(() => {
  return {
    stateValue: stateValue,
    setStateValue: setStateValue,
    stateValue1: stateValue1,
    setStateValue1: setStateValue1
  }
}, [stateValue, stateValue1])
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use hooks or custom hooks, the states from them are indivisual.
which means suppose you used useReducer in Component A and B. state from useReducer in A, B is totally different whereas if you use contextAPI the state is same.