# Is useCallback best way to get props data from child component to parent components?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

Is useCallback best way to get props data from child component to parent components?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If this may be helpful, please [read the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) for `useCallback`. The `useCallback` hook is somewhat similar to `useMemo`. The technique of `memoization` is used to avoid repetition of certain expensive tasks. Please review what [Wiki says about Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), if it helps. In order to send data up from child to parent components, `callback` functions may be employed. May be this is relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my perspective there are two common options here:

1. Passing down a callback function (created using useCallback or otherwise):

```
...
function Parent() {

    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    // Can also just pass setText directly
    function onClick() {
        setText('new text');
    }

    return (
        <Child onClick={onClick} />
    );

}

function Child(props) {
    return (
        <button onClick={props.onClick}>Click Me</button>
    );
}
```

Pros: Simple

2. Use the Context API and consume the state

If the child is deeply nested, to avoid prop drilling (and to make the state easily available to other components), you could use the [ContextAPI](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext):

*TextProvider.js*

```
...
const TextContext = createContext('');

export function TextProvider(children) {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const value = {
        text, setText
    };

    return <TextContext.Provider value={text}>
        {children}
    </TextContext.Provider>;
};

export function useText() {
    const context = useContext(ClientContext);
    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error('useSocket must be used within a SocketProvider');
    }

    return context;
};
```

*App.js* (or whatever file renders the `<Parent />`) - wrap the Parent in the provider:

```
function App() {
    return (
    ...
    <TextProvider>
        <Parent />
    </TextProvider>
    ...
    );
}
```

*Child.js*

```
function Child(props) {
    const { text, setText } = useText();

    function onClick() {
        setText('hello'); // Will update "text" state on parent
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={onClick}>Click Me</button>
    );
}
```

Pros: Useful when passing props into a deeply nested component. This post here details some more pros/cons of the [ContextAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66786825/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-on-using-react-context-api-with-the-usereducer-hook)